# <ask> configure mysql and freeradius

Tags: mysql, freeradius

I just installed freeradius from tarbal version, freeradius-server-2.2.0.tar.gz.
comile and make install running well.i also can running radius -X to run on debug mode firstly.

Then i try to configure freeradius in order to can run using mysql database.

I configure authorizaion,accounting on sites-available/default, uncoment include sql on radiusd.conf and configure connection on sql.conf

Then i import schema to mysql database from schema.sql and nas.sql

Then when i try to running radiusd -X i got error like bellow :

```
Could not link driver rlm_sql_mysql: rlm_sql_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Make sure it (and all its dependent libraries!) are in the search path of your system's ld.
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sql.conf[22]: Instantiation failed for module "sql"
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[177]: Failed to find "sql" in the "modules" section.
/usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default[69]: Errors parsing authorize section.
```

Anyone could help me how to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Did you uncomment the "$INCLUDE sql.conf" in radiusd.conf?

And if you use Debian, ubuntu ... try "apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev"

Comment: Actually everyting running well after i installed libmysqlclient-* with apt-get.